# boost::lexical_cast from string to char exception

Tags: c++, boost, lexical-cast

I am new to using boost::lexical_cast and have minimal understanding of its internals. I am trying to do the following cast:

```
string someString = boost::lexical_cast<char>(sourceString);
```

However, boost is complaining that the above code is:

[Exception]: bad lexical cast: source type value could not be interpreted as target

The source is a string, however it will always only be 1 character long.

Could someone please explain?

Thanks.

Comment: Was there a reason you're doing that instead of something like `char c = *(sourceString.c_str());`? And why are you turning a string into a char and putting it back into a string?

Comment: Or perhaps `char c = sourceString[0];`?

Comment: @MikeSeymour or you could just do that...

Comment: @set - sorry i didn't write that part properly, i meant to declare it as a char. i could do that, but i would just like to understand why boost cannot convert it properly. thanks

Comment: Also, this won't compile, since you can't convert the `char` result of `lexical_cast<char>` to a string. Once I fix that, the code [works](http://ideone.com/BkGOy) as long as `sourceString` contains a single character.

Comment: What @Mike said; `string` doesn't have a constructor taking a `char`. You could probably do `string someString(boost::lexical_cast<char>(sourceString), 1);` and make it work, but that is the _really long way around_. You're far better off doing `char str = otherstr[0]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I test it (after fixing the invalid conversion from `char` to `string`), the lexical cast succeeds as long as `sourceString` contains a single character. [Here are the test results.](http://ideone.com/BkGOy)

If your real code doesn't work, then please post more of it; preferably a runnable program that demonstrates the error.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I have a vector<string> and I know that string at position index x would only be one character, so essentially I am doing the following: char someChar = lexical_cast<char>(tokens[x]); this is what is throwing the error. Sorry, should have posted that before. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you should check your assumptions; add `assert(tokens[x].length() == 1);` before the cast to make sure that what you know is actually what is happening.

Comment: yes Mike you are correct, my assumption was incorrect. Thanks!